# Why not make some methods in com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper static?

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my project i used a lot com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper to deal with JSON, for example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
A a = mapper.readValue(file.getBytes(), A.class);
```

At first sight I think it's better it's better to make the readValue method static, then we can use it as ObjectMapper.readValue(), much more clear. But I know there must be some reasons that it shouldn't, does anyone know it?

Comment: Look at other constructors of ObjectMapper. ObjectMapper(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory jf) and ObjectMapper(JsonFactory jf, DefaultSerializerProvider sp,               DefaultDeserializationContext dc). ObjectMapper class can be configured in many ways using those arguments. And each part of an application can use different configurations based on their needs. You can't really do that statically (you can but you better not). This isn't the only reason but one from usability perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other reason is with each instance of ObjectMapper you bind certain specific confuguration ready by ObjectMapper while serialization and desrialization process somethinglike below.
 So you can configure different startegies while object conversion process.

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
   String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new MyBean());
```